# Gitlab Hide Projects From Dashboard

Tags: gitlab

**Problem**
I have a gitlab with a lot of old repositories. I want to mention my gitlab as a reference on my CV but I do not want all the old repositories to appear there, just the more relevant ones.
Just making the projects private is not enough as this leaves a lot of clutter in my dashboard and it is hard to see the projects I am trying to showcase.
I do not want to delete the old projects, as I want access to them in the future, I just want to hide them from other people to see that they even exist.

**What I Tried**
I tried archiving the old projects but they still appear on my Projects lists, just with an archived tag.
I saw mentions of playing with the "Metrics Dashboard" under the visibility settings but this is greyed out for me + I  do not think this is what I need from my understanding.

**Required Result**
For me to be able to choose which projects appear and do not appear in my gitlab dashboard.

Thanks in advance for any help available!

---

### EDIT

I found out that I can star and un-star projects, and that will count as activity on the project without actually changing anything. As the dashboard displays projects by when there was last activity on them then you can actually arrange your project by staring and un-staring the projects in the reverse order you want them to appear.

This somewhat does what I want, but with an ugly work around. Also it will always display 10 projects as far as I can tell, so if I want to only showcase 6 of them the best I can do is push the 4 I don't want to the bottom, but I still can't hide them completely.
This is why I am not writing this as an answer to my question. There has to be a way to just tell a project to be hidden or arrange the projects without this ugly workaround, and if there truly by design isn't a way of doing this then it will also just be good to be officially told that.

Comment: What version of GitLab are you running? CE or EE?

Comment: I am just using the web version of GitLab. Do I need to download the software?

Comment: No need to download it. CE = Community Edition (free), EE = Enterprise Edition (paid). I'm guessing you're using the free version, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using the free one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitLab [Groups](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2014/06/30/feature-highlight-groups/) do exactly what you need. See [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/) for more info.

- You can assign each project to a different group
- You can move a project from one group to another as needed
- You can assign different permissions and visibility for each group
- You can also create [subgroups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/subgroups/index.html)
- Each group/subgroup is treated as a separate namespace, meaning you access it using a different URL

So you can define a **public** group called `yourfullname` and a **public** subgroup called `portfolio`. Move the projects you want prospective employers to view to the `portfolio` subgroup and make sure their visibility is also public. All other groups/subgroups should be **private**. Then people can access your projects by visiting the following URL:

> gitlab.com/yourfullname/portfolio

You can still view all of your projects in a single dashboard if you want, or you can view all projects within a group or sub-group by navigating to the desired group URL or dashboard. In the image below, `archive` and `development` are private (see the lock icon), but `portfolio` is public:

[image]